# Styling iframes in IE8?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Say I have the following code:

```
<style>
iframe
{
    border:none;
}
div
{
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div>
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

If I view this in any modern browser there is no border around the iframe.  But If I view it using IE8 or 7 then the border remains.  How can I make the border disappear for older, crappier browsers?

I am also having a few other styling issues with the iframe, so bonus points for anyone can provide a good link that goes over cross browser styling of iframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the following to the iFrame. It's can't be done with just CSS for older browsers:

```
frameborder="0"
```